# How to check if a particular user has downloaded my android app?

Tags: google-play-store, downloading

We have users using both website and android app. I want to know if a user on my website has downloaded the app also(even if he has not started using it). I have user's email address and phone number.

Comment: You can call him or write him an email and ask.

Comment: This is not for a single user. Will be repeating for all the users.

Comment: You haven't specified where you put the app (Play Store? Your website?), but it's impossible to know. Why not permit the download if user has logged-in to your website?

Comment: If you used email address in your application, then you can use any 3rd party analytics tools such as https://parse.com/ and http://www.localytics.com/ by sending email Id of user in property to find which user has downloaded your app

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen I can send URL with email address signature. But how can i know if the user has actually downloaded the app?

Answer (score 0):

you can not do any such user specific metric collection as for as i understand.
You may need to refer this [Campaign](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns)